# All points along a line at a particular angle

Tags: math, line, point, angle

I have got a point (x0,y0). I want to find all points along the line starting at (x0,y0) which is at an angle theta with respect to the x axis. I have got only (x0,y0) and theta at my hand. nothing more. How do I go about this?

Comment: This question is better suited for http://math.stackexchange.com. You'll get more in depth answers there. Cheers!

Comment: @MBlanc Actually more a computing problem. For a mathmatician there would be an infinite number of points, which I assume is not required. For a finite number of points you probably want the  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham's_line_algorithm. But it may be better to use the appropriate library function `drawLine(x0,y0,x0+r *cos(angle),y0 + r* sin(angle))`.

Answer (score 1):

The cosine of the angle gives you the steps to take in the x-direction, and the sine of the angle gives you the steps to take in the y-direction. It's better to take this approach rather than finding the gradient of the line because for a vertical line the gradient is infinite.

You can't find *all* points on a computer, because there are an infinite number of them, so you have to decide on a step-size and the number of steps. This is illustrated in the Python program below which chooses a step-size of 1 and 100 steps.

```R
import math, matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def pts(x0,y0,theta):
    t = range(101) # t=0,1,2,3,4,5...,100
    x = [x0 + tt*math.cos(theta) for tt in t]
    y = [y0 + tt*math.sin(theta) for tt in t]
    return x,y

def degrees2radians(degrees):
    return degrees * math.pi/180

degrees = 45
x,y=pts(-100,-100, degrees2radians(degrees))
plt.plot(x, y, label='{} degrees'.format(degrees))

degrees = 90
x,y=pts(100,100, degrees2radians(degrees))
plt.plot(x, y, label='{} degrees'.format(degrees))

plt.xlim(-100,300)
plt.ylim(-100,300)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

and outputs

[image]

The R program below takes a similar approach.

```R
drawline=function(x0,y0,theta) {
    t=0:100 # t = 0,1,2,3,4,5,...,100
    # x formed by stepping by cos theta each time
    x=x0 + t*cos(theta)
    # y formed by stepping by sin theta each time
    y=y0 + t*sin(theta)
    # plot
    rng=c(min(x,y),max(x,y)) # range
    plot(y~x,xlim=rng,ylim=rng,type="l")
}
```

Here, `theta` is in radians. So `drawline(-100,-100,pi/4)` corresponds to 45 degrees and gives the first plot, whereas `drawline(100,100,pi/2)` corresponds to 90 degrees and gives the vertical line shown on the left of the second plot.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Another problem I'm facing is that I need to generate the integer coordinates, say 10 of them, along the line starting at (x0, y0) at an angle theta because I am working with an image. If I use floor or ceil on cosine or sine of the angle, I may be generating the same coordinates multiple times. How do I go about this?

Comment: @user3488947 in that case you can use en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham's_line_algorithm as mentioned in Salix alba's comment.

Comment: But Bresenham's algorithm requires two points on the line. Isn't it?

Comment: @user3488947 To get the second point you can use my answer: just do one step with an appropriate step-size.